# Проблемы с вопросами/ответами в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

Решил посмотреть что за тестовые задания в очереди проверок. Включил фильтр по [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) и [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). В итоге получил очевидно проверочное задание по вот [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464176/) вопросу.

Мало того, что открыв его вне очереди сразу видно, что он закрыт уже, но и метка под ним всего одна - [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

**Итого:** надо хотя бы при наличии фильтра показывать тестовые задания под этот фильтр подходящие.

**UPD_0:**

В [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25554874#25554874) ещё жалуются на повторы тестовых заданий.

**UPD_1:**

В чате же ещё [упоминают](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25624186#25624186) ответ-ловушку. Ответ-ссылка, удалён модератором, но при этом в комментах имеет ссылку на обсуждение на мету с общим решением о том, что ответ норм, т.к. ТС просил именно ссылку.

**UPD_2:**

Вот [ещё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/45691): достаточно поглядеть на репу автора чтобы понять, что это проверка)

Comment: Всё верно, когда открываешь вопрос по ссылке, видно его настоящее состояние. А вы как хотите, чтобы разворачивался целый поддельный StackOverflow? ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не с этим моментом я согласен) А вот то, что мне при фильтрах указанных крестопроблемы показывают... =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вообще-то раньше разворачивался, если память не изменяет...

Comment: Так ведь тестовые задания - это защита от роботов и бездумного тыкания. Если внимательно и вручную проверять очередь, в том числе открывая проверяемые вопросы в отдельной вкладке, то распознавание тестовых заданий и не должно представлять собой что-то сложное.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На сколько мне известно, к сожалению, нет возможности исключить какие-либо вопросы из аудита *напрямую*. Система автоматически подбирает вопросы для проверки правильности действий участников.

Как было правильно указано в комментариях, основное назначение системы аудита – проверка честности участников, то есть она призвана ограничить доступ к сайту лишь тем, кто даже не пытается вникнуть в суть сообщений. Не более.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Если вдруг когда-нибудь решат чуть улучшить алгоритм подбора тестовых заданий - то в вопросе два бага обозначены: фильтр по меткам к ним не применяется и они повторяются.

Comment: Я еще раз подниму вопрос аудита на планерке. Попробую найти больше информации по системе и её идеологии.